# How to use an accordion into another accordion ? (or tabs or collapse)

Tags: magento2, adminhtml, forms

I'm trying to put an accordion into another, 
and the lonely way I found is to not use the same widget into another.

Exemple, 
the parent is an accordion, 
the different children can be tabs.

The opposite works.

But, if i'm right, 
I understood that it's not possible to use the same widget for the parent and the children.

My problem, 
I have an accordion who has 4 forms, 
each form as several tabs (if you select this, you have this input...)
AND I need to put another accordion or tab in the last tab.

What can I do ?

Comment: do you need in admin side?

Answer (score 0):

add this code in your UI component form.

```
<fieldset name="general">
<argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
<item name="config" xsi:type="array">
    <item name="collapsible" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Aditional Options</item>
    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">100</item>
</item>
</argument>
<fieldset name="banners">
<argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
    <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="collapsible" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
        <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Top Banner On Product Pager</item>
        <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">100</item>
    </item>
</argument>
<field name="product_top_banner_alt">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="label" xsi:type="string">Alt Text:</item>
            <item name="visible" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
            <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
            <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">input</item>
            <item name="source" xsi:type="string">catalog_rule</item>
            <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
            </item>
        </item>
    </argument>
</field>
</fieldset>
<!--After Product-->
<fieldset name="after_banners">
<argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
    <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="collapsible" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
        <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">After Product Description Banner</item>
        <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">160</item>
    </item>
</argument>
<field name="product_after_banner_alt">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="label" xsi:type="string">Alt Text:</item>
            <item name="visible" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
            <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
            <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">input</item>
            <item name="source" xsi:type="string">catalog_rule</item>
            <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
            </item>
        </item>
    </argument>
</field>
</fieldset>
<!--Label-->
<fieldset name="labels">
<argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
    <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="collapsible" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
        <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Labels</item>
        <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">170</item>
    </item>
</argument>

<field name="product_labels_alt">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="label" xsi:type="string">Alt Text:</item>
            <item name="visible" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
            <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
            <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">input</item>
            <item name="source" xsi:type="string">product_labels_alt</item>
            <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
            </item>
        </item>
    </argument>
</field>
```